# Incrementing a variable when the user gets the correct answer

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem / serious bug, which I can't seem to resolve on my own, though I am still building the app, I want the app to increment the variable `storesTotalCorrectAnswer` whenever the user checked the radio button (that contains the correct answer) but I thought it was working until I starting noticing that the scores were not accurate, so I added a toast message and the toast message isn't displaying on the app, so I knew that the `storesTotalCorrectAnswer` variable isn't working as intended.

Please - how do I solve this bug?

What I want to achieve is to increment the `storesTotalCorrectAnswer` when the user check the radio button that contains the correct answer.

I have tried various ways including using an `if` statement on almost everywhere in the code but now seems to be working

```
 com.myafrica.africaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//this variable stores the total number of correct answers
int storesTotalCorrectAnswer = 0;

//this variable counts the total number of randomQuestions asked
int randomNumberCounter = 0;

//this variable stores the random numbers generated
int randomNumber = 0;


//this variables stores the views for public access to other methods
TextView testQuestionID;

RadioButton answerA_ID;
RadioButton answerB_ID;
RadioButton answerC_ID;
RadioButton answerD_ID;

RadioGroup radioGroup_ID;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get the text view and stores it in this variable
    testQuestionID = findViewById(R.id.testQuestion);

    //get the radio button view and stores it in this variable
    answerA_ID = findViewById(R.id.answerA);
    answerB_ID = findViewById(R.id.answerB);
    answerC_ID = findViewById(R.id.answerC);
    answerD_ID = findViewById(R.id.answerD);

    //get the radio group ID and stores it for future reference
    radioGroup_ID = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_ID);

   }

//When the onclicked() is clicked this method runs
public void GetNextQuestion(View view) {

    randomNumberGenerator();

    //just to know when the onClicks runs
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NEXT  is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

//the random number generator method
public void randomNumberGenerator() {

    //the random number generator
    Random ranNum = new Random();
    randomNumber = ranNum.nextInt(4) + 1;

    //to stop the questions from displaying once the required number is reached
    if (randomNumberCounter < 4) {

        //to know how many times the random method has been called
        while (randomNumber > 0) {
            randomNumberCounter++;

            switch (randomNumber) {

                /* When the randomNumber is generated (number from 1 to 4)
                 * it matches the case and displays the required question */

                case 1:
                    question1();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    question2();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    question3();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    question4();
                    break;
            }

            break;

        }
    }

    // shows a next layout after the question stops showing
    else {
        Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        secondActivity.putExtra("secondActivity", "" + storesTotalCorrectAnswer);
        startActivity(secondActivity);
    }
}


/*
 * This part of the code will contain the questions and answer part of the quiz app.
 * Each question and answer is a method that will called when the Next button is clicked in the app.
 * When the button is clicked the setText() will automatically (re)set the text in the text layout in the XML
 */

public void question1() {
    testQuestionID.setText("Which part of Africa can Ghana be located");
    answerA_ID.setText(" A: West Africa");
    answerB_ID.setText(" B: East Africa");
    answerC_ID.setText(" C: Central Africa");
    answerD_ID.setText(" D: North Africa");

    //wanted to increment the storesTotalCorrectAnswer when the correct radio button is clicked and displayed a toast message

    if (answerA_ID.isChecked()) {
        storesTotalCorrectAnswer++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 1 Answer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    radioGroup_ID.clearCheck();

}

public void question2() {
    testQuestionID.setText("What is the capital of Nigeria");
    answerA_ID.setText(" A: Abuja");
    answerB_ID.setText(" B: Kano");
    answerC_ID.setText(" C: Lagos");
    answerD_ID.setText(" D: Port Harourt");

    //wanted to increment the storesTotalCorrectAnswer when the correct radio button is clicked and displayed a toast message

    if (answerA_ID.isChecked()) {
        storesTotalCorrectAnswer++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 2 Answer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    radioGroup_ID.clearCheck();
}

public void question3() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 2 Answer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    testQuestionID.setText("Which of these countries are not located in Africa");
    answerA_ID.setText(" A: Niger");
    answerB_ID.setText(" B: Nigeria");
    answerC_ID.setText(" C: Rwanda");
    answerD_ID.setText(" D: Non of the Above");

    //wanted to increment the storesTotalCorrectAnswer when the correct radio button is clicked and displayed a toast message

    if (answerD_ID.isChecked()) {
        storesTotalCorrectAnswer++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 3  Answer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    radioGroup_ID.clearCheck();
}

public void question4() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 2 Answer is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    testQuestionID.setText("What is the estimated population of Africa, as at 2015");
    answerA_ID.setText(" A: 1.2 Billion");
    answerB_ID.setText(" B: 500 Billion");
    answerC_ID.setText(" C: 2 Billion");
    answerD_ID.setText(" D: 360 million");

    //wanted to increment the storesTotalCorrectAnswer when the correct radio button is clicked and displayed a toast message

    if (answerA_ID.isChecked()) {
        storesTotalCorrectAnswer++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question 4  is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    radioGroup_ID.clearCheck();
}

/* END OF CODE */
}
```

Comment: storesTotalCorrectAnswer should not affect whether a Toast will appear or not. If you can't get a Toast to appear, it would be for some other reason.

Comment: I decided to include the Toast when I noticed that the output wasn't displaying  Intended, so if the code was running fine the Toast would have displayed.

Comment: You need to debug your code, and SO is a terrible debugger! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @jdv thanks i will read that up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working fine, the only problem is on your if-statements. You said you want it 1 to 4, but the condition is checking >0 and <4 which means 1 to 3. Whenever the randomNumber is 4 it will not work, so change the `if (randomNumberCounter < 4)` to `if (randomNumberCounter <= 4)`.

Comment: Oh i didn't see that. i did change it and notice that i get a total of 5 questions now i am still wondering why? Meanwhile the initial bug i was experiencing still continues. I believe the `if (answerA_ID.isChecked())` always returns true even if the radio button is clicked or not

Comment: looking at the code above you would see that `int randomNumberCounter = 0;` and  `if (randomNumberCounter < 4) {
        while (randomNumber > 0) {
            randomNumberCounter++;` thats the first number sent is zero (0) after that it's start incrementing by 1, that explains when i changed it to `if (randomNumberCounter <= 4)` from `if (randomNumberCounter < 4)` it started generating 5 question i could change it to `if (randomNumberCounter <= 3)` so i dont confused users.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to display your value using Logcat or

`if (answerA_ID.isChecked()) {
        System.out.println("Right Answer");
    }`

*If it's showing the answer then use this (++storesTotalCorrectAnswer) Instead of  this (storesTotalCorrectAnswer++)*

Comment: i believe that `if (answerA_ID.isChecked())` always returns true even if the radio button is checked or not.

Comment: hope you have use this (++storesTotalCorrectAnswer) Instead of this (storesTotalCorrectAnswer++)??

Comment: Yes I did use `++storesTotalCorrectAnswer`.